# Как брать данные понемногу?

Tags: java, android

Есть сервис и при обращении к нему он возвращает ответ обьемом 20+мб и я парсю эти данные .Но вот беда если вдруг сеть оборвется я он загрузил ток 15 мб то при восановлении придется докачивать с 0.Можно ли как то грузить данные по немногу ?допустим там 20 мегабайт я скачал 1 мегабайт пропарсил затем осальные 19 так же.Для подключения к сервису использую стандартный класс `HttpUrlConnection`.Вот предварительный кусок кода

```
String url = "**************************";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
       int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

Comment: Думаю, вам нужно разработчиков серверной части спросить.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja а можно поточнее ??

Comment: Просто задайте свой вопрос им, а не здесь.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja причем тут они ) с сервисом всё окей я ищу способ буферрного скачивания на самом телефоне

Comment: А как вы собираетесь начать закачку с места обрыва, если сервер этого не позволяет? Чудес тут нет.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  вот теперь ясно стало )))сервер тож я собираю)хотя что там делать незнаю ,подскажите в каком напрвлении капать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок, раз сервер под вашим контролем, то вот советы:

*Сложный путь.*
Читайте про HTTP Range параметр, можете начать с секции
**14.35.2 Range Retrieval Requests**
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

HTTP сервер должен поддерживать эту фичу протокола.
И ваши данные не должны меняться, т.е. повторный запрос должен вернуть тот же набор данных, иначе все зря.

*Путь попроще*, по которому чаще идут.
Пагинация или постраничное скачивание данных.
В каждый запрос добавляются доп параметры, например: page и records.
Второй по желанию, сервер может иметь значение по умолчанию (500 например, если о JSON объектах).

И начинаете страница за страницей скачивать данные, оборвалось - повторяете страницу. Если сервер вернул данных меньше чем records, значит это последняя страница.

Это идея в общем, вариантов имплементации много.

Comment: АААА вот 2 вариант мне болеее по душе )))) его реализовать не так сложно будет думаю